# invalid use of group

Tags: php, mysql

i've been trying to do this on php, reading from a db table in mysql, but i cant understand what's the error on it. can someon help me please?
the table as a column that contains numbers (this numbers represent a course :P)

```
SELECT *, MAX(COUNT(mi_curso)) maximo
FROM producto
GROUP BY mi_curso
```

and this is the error shown:

```
consulta SQL:
SELECT *, MAX(COUNT(mi_curso)) maximo
FROM producto
GROUP BY mi_curso LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación 
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

Comment: sorry, the last part is MySQL ha dicho: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: Update your question with sample input and desired output.  As it stands now, the question is vague.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to nest two aggregate functions, which is not working.  Instead, use one of the following two queries:

```
SELECT *, MAX(mi_curso) maximo
FROM producto
GROUP BY mi_curso
```

or

```
SELECT *, COUNT(mi_curso) maximo
FROM producto
GROUP BY mi_curso
```

Comment: Note: I will update/change my answer if @Jeferson tells us what he actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

could you try the following and comment if this worked?

```
SELECT id, COUNT(mi_curso) maximo FROM producto GROUP BY mi_curso having max(count(mi_curso))
```

**edit: as suggested by Tim Biegeleisen**

```
SELECT id, COUNT(mi_curso) maximo FROM producto GROUP BY mi_curso having max(count(maximo))
```

Comment: Isn't this still nesting two aggregate functions?

Comment: i think this is just to count how many time a number repeats himself inside the column, no? te second one, the first one is just taking the maximun value without make the count

Comment: if it doesn't work I recommend using @TimBiegeleisen 's answer

Comment: the first one display the number and in the end limits to show only the max of the count, but the second one is an improvement as suggested by @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @JefersonTapias Please update your question so we don't all have to guess what you are thinking.

Answer (score 0):

How about probably the most common problem with group by....

Including non-aggregates in the select list....

`select *` probably contains some column other than mi_curso.
If so, this group by doesn't work.

You can select aggregates, and columns included in the GROUP BY expression.

If you do (for example)

```
select name, address, count(name)
from residences
group by name
```

What value should sql deliver for address when one person has >1 residences? No way for it to know.

Some sql's give nice clear error messages. Some just wink at you, as if you already know what's wrong.